# Eberhard-type theorems for Fisk triangulations?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, triangulations, degree-sequence

A triangulation of a surface is called a Fisk triangulation if the degree of all but two vertices is even, and these two exceptional vertices of odd degree are neighbors.
I would like to know what conditions must be satisfied by the degree sequence of such graphs.
I've found several results about the degree sequences of *general* triangulations of surfaces, but nothing about Fisk triangulations.
Can we, for example, have that every even degree equals 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Günter Rote has just shown me a (5,6,..,6,7) triangulation of the Klein-bottle where 5 and 7 are neighbors. He has also found several similar higher genus triangulations.

Answer (score 5):

This is only a partial answer.

First, a sphere does not admit Fisk triangulations. Fisk has proved it by using the 4-color theorem, but there is a simpler proof using Fisk's method of coloring monodromy. Try to color the vertices in three colors. There will be no contradiction when you go around an even vertex; but the colors will be permuted when you go around an odd vertex. For one vertex this will be the $(12)$ transposition, for the other vertex $(23)$ transposition. Thus, the fundamental group of the sphere minus two points will be mapped epimorphically onto $S_3$, which is a contradiction.

The torus does not allow triangulations with vertex degrees $5, 7, 6, \ldots, 6$ (even if you don't require the $5$- and the $7$-vertex to be neighbors). This is a result by Jendrol and Jukovic, reproved recently by a geometric method. There is however a "pseudotriangulation" (in the sense that it is not a simplicial complex) with two vertices, one of degree $3$, the other of degree $9$. If you cut it open along an edge and glue to a $6$-regular torus cut open along an edge, then you get a surface of genus two with vertices of degrees $9$ and $15$. This can be iterated. (Again, the result is a pseudotriangulation.)

But if there is a $(3,9)$ Fisk triangulation of the torus, then there is also a $6$-regular Fisk triangulation of an orientable surface of any genus. Instead of cutting along edges, cut the $(3,9)$-torus and a $6$-regular torus along two-edge paths (for the $(3,9)$-torus take a path between the exceptional vertices. The cut open tori can be glued together so that the odd vertices remain odd and adjacent, and all other vertices keep degree $6$. This gluing will not create a double edge as the previous construction.

EDIT: On the other hand, I am starting to doubt the existence of a $(3,9)$-triangulation of the torus. Maybe one can prove by geometric methods that in the canonical Euclidean cone-metric there are several shortest geodesics between the exceptional points. This would mean, there must be multiple edges in the skeleton of the triangulation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I knew most of these results, as I'm familiar with some of your work. But I didn't really get your last para. Which statement would follow from which? What I would be really interested in is a Fisk triangulation without short non-contractible cycles.

Comment: I have edited the last paragraph, hopefully it is clearer now. On the other hand, for the torus it seems to me now that the "(3,9) Fisk" triangulation will necessarily have a multiple edge.

Comment: What is an "odd Fisk"? Is it the triangulation in question? (I would call it 6-regular Fisk, as I see nothing odd about it, so maybe you mean something else.) And just to summarize: You've proved that if such a triangulation exists for the torus, then it exists for every orientable surface, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have adjusted the terminology now. And right, I am proving this implication (although one should be a bit careful and watch for double edges in this situation as well).